# Cant git clone from my raspberry

Tags: networking, static-ip, git

Trying to git clone a repo but receiving strange error

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ git clone git://github.com/MalcolmRobb/dump1090.git
Cloning into 'dump1090'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com: Name or service not known
```

I followed this [tutorial](http://weworkweplay.com/play/automatically-connect-a-raspberry-pi-to-a-wifi-network/) to fix my ip on the wifi , all is working fine i can ssh to raspi on LAN and also from external IP (ports forwarded on Router).

below my actual interfaces configurations.

## /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto wlan0

iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0

iface wlan0 inet static

address 192.168.1.101

netmask 255.255.255.0

gateway 192.168.1.1

wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface default inet dhcp
```

Comment: can you just type "ping github.com" if you get something like "host unknown" you are not connected to the internet correctly. Also try "ping  192.30.252.129" which is the IP address I get when resolving github.com

Comment: Can you also edit your question and include the output of ifconfig

Answer (score 3):

Ok seems that i was able to fix the issue adding nameservers to resolf.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

then add the server IP of the openDNS as eg.

```
nameserver  208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```